How to Position a Floating '+' Button Below a List in SwiftUI?
I’ve been learning Swift and app design and practicing by replicating the styles of existing applications. Recently, I faced a challenge with positioning a '+' button directly below a list in SwiftUI.
Problem Details
I want to achieve a design similar to this Todo list app to copy
My main challenge is placing the '+' button right below the list. I’ve experimented with two approaches:
(1) Button Below the List in a VStack:
This method positions the button directly below the list, but it results in hard edges at the bottom of the last list item.
(2) Button in a Section Below the List:
While this positions the button correctly in a new Section, it creates excessive space, pushing the button too far down from the last list item.
Code Examples
Concept (1): Button Below the List
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "circle") // Placeholder for checkbox
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
            
            Button(action: addItem) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(.black) // Color of the plus icon
                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        }
    }
}

concept (1)
Concept (2): Button in a Section Below the List
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "circle") // Placeholder for checkbox
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
            
            Section {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(.black) // Color of the plus icon
                    }
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            }
        }
    }
}

concept (2)
Question
Does anyone have suggestions on how to position the '+' button to seamlessly sit below the last item in the list without creating gaps or hard edges? Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
Edit:
Whenever I try to add a footer I'm getting this -
Code:
var body: some View {
    
    Section {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "circle")
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    } footer: {
        VStack {
            Spacer() //<- extra spacer to match with the design
            
            Button(action: addItem) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        }
    }
    
}

and looks like this:

fyi:
I've messed around the spacer/removed and it still doesn't work.

You can wrap into a Section and then provide a Section Footer, something like:
Section {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "circle")
            Text(item)
        }
    }
} footer: {
    VStack {
        Spacer() //<- extra spacer to match with the design
        
        Button(action: action) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
    }
}

Output:


Tried this and I'm getting something different.
Responded in post.
Thanks!

oh, actually, Section must be nested inside List.

I found this:
var body: some View {
    
    List {
        Section(
            footer: VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
            }
        ) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "circle")
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}

And it worked:

